# PowerShell rename UNC path

Tags: powershell, unc

how to rename UNC path?

The old path I extract from AD.

```
$ADUser = Get-AdUser -Filter {SamAccountName -eq $AD_old_username} -Properties HomeDirectory,GivenName,SurName
$string = $ADUser.HomeDirectory #Old user home dir path
```

Output for `$string`  is: `\\domain\1\2\\$AD_old_username\Data`

The new path I get by renaming username.

```
$array = $string -split " "

$newpath = if($array -match "$AD_old_username") {
    $array -replace "$AD_old_username","$AD_NEW_UserName"
}
```

Output for newpath  is: `\\domain\1\2\\$AD_new_username\Data`

The `Rename-Item -Path $string -NewName $newpath` does not work, please help?

Comment: Is there some reason that you can't just drop the `\DATA` and then use `Rename-Item`?

Comment: That is how AD path is setup. I'm not sure what that would do to UNC, 
Would i need to do something like this? 
`$unc1 = $string - "data folder" `

Then `Rename-Item -Path $unc1 -NewName $AD_NEW_UserName` ?

Comment: You'll find the [`Split-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/split-path?view=powershell-5.1) cmdlet to be useful, and specifically the `-Parent` parameter. You might also find [`Join-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path?view=powershell-5.1) useful.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you need, you're looking to modify the `HomeDirectory` of an `ADUser` ?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon looking to rename network path

Comment: Why is there a double backslash inside the paths ? (`\1\2\\NewUserName\Data`)

Comment: Thank you @JeffZeitlin your suggestion.

All I have to do is remove \data as you suggested and then Rename-Item worked. 

`$string = $ADUser.HomeDirectory`
`$string = $string.Substring(0, $string.lastIndexOf('\'))`
`Rename-Item -Path $string -NewName $newpath`